# Android - Retrieve a path of an picked image

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-image, android-file

I have java code to pick an image from gallery or camera. In this code when user picks an image then it gets cropped into 200x200 size. I am looking for absolute path of that cropped image and I want to move that cropped image into SD card. But I am not getting the path with file extension. When I tried to get path then it is returning path with file name including random number like below.

```
/storage/media/865412
```

I am unable to move this file. I need the absolute path with the file extension.

**ProfileInfo.java**

```
public class ProfileInfo extends Activity {
    private Uri mImageCaptureUri;
    private ImageView mImageView;

    private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
    private static final int CROP_FROM_CAMERA = 2;
    private static final int PICK_FROM_FILE = 3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.profile_info);

        final String [] items           = new String [] {"Take from camera", "Select from gallery"};                
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter    = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,items);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder     = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Select Image");
        builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) { //pick from camera
                if (item == 0) {
                    Intent intent    = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                       "tmp_avatar_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

                    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);

                    try {
                        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else { //pick from file
                    Intent intent = new Intent();

                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
                }
            }
        } );

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        mImageView  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);

        mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

        switch (requestCode) {
            case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
                doCrop();

                break;

            case PICK_FROM_FILE: 
                mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();

                doCrop();

                break;          

            case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:          
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

                if (extras != null) {               
                    Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");

                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(photo);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            photo.getWidth()+"x"+photo.getHeight()+"\n"+photo.getByteCount()+"\n", 
                            0).show();
                }

                File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());            

                if (f.exists()) f.delete();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),mImageCaptureUri.getPath(), 0).show();

                break;

        }
    }

    private void doCrop() {
        final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setType("image/*");

        List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );

        int size = list.size();

        if (size == 0) {            
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return;
        } else {
            intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

            intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            intent.putExtra("scale", true);
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

            if (size == 1) {
                Intent i        = new Intent(intent);
                ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

                i.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

                startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
            } else {
                for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                    final CropOption co = new CropOption();

                    co.title    = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.icon     = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.appIntent= new Intent(intent);

                    co.appIntent.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

                    cropOptions.add(co);
                }

                CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
                builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) {
                        startActivityForResult( cropOptions.get(item).appIntent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                    }
                });

                builder.setOnCancelListener( new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel( DialogInterface dialog ) {

                        if (mImageCaptureUri != null ) {
                            getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null, null );
                            mImageCaptureUri = null;
                        }
                    }
                } );

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                alert.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**profile_info.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/activity_bg_color"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.beproject.ourway.ProfileInfo" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:text="Tap on image to change (Optional)"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
            android:layout_width="156dp"
            android:layout_height="156dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/user" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/your_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Your name..."
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColorHint="#DFDFDF" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/skip_image_upload"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flat_button_selector"
        android:text="Skip"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/image_upload"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="73dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flat_button_selector"
        android:onClick="uploadImage"
        android:text="Upload"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**CropOptionAdapter.java**

```
public class CropOptionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CropOption> {
    private ArrayList<CropOption> mOptions;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CropOptionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CropOption> options) {
        super(context, R.layout.crop_selector, options);

        mOptions    = options;

        mInflater   = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup group) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.crop_selector, null);

        CropOption item = mOptions.get(position);

        if (item != null) {
            ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon)).setImageDrawable(item.icon);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name)).setText(item.title);

            return convertView;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**CropOption.java**

```
public class CropOption {
    public CharSequence title;
    public Drawable icon;
    public Intent appIntent;
}
```

**crop_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `I am looking for absolute path of that cropped image `. The cropped image has no path as what you get in onActivityResult is a bitmap. So you can do with that bitmap what you want. It is not saved yet cropped. The original image is unharmed/uncropped. Well that's what i experienced.

Comment: But how to save that cropped image? I am confused.

Comment: Well you have the Bitmap already. So save that Bitmap to file. Code for that has been posted many times on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need the absolute file path in order to copy the file, because you can open an `InputStream` from the `Uri` directly and copy the contents from that:

```
void copyFileFromUri(Uri sourceUri, String destFilePath) throws IOException 
{
    InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(sourceUri);
    File outFile = new File(destFilePath);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
    copyFile(in, out);
}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
       out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

copyFile() function copied from answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-from-assets-folder-to-sdcard)

Comment: where you were going to copy the file using the absolute file path, call this function to copy it with the Uri instead